# I´m trying to writing a .txt on windows server 12 using ip addres from a raspberry

Tags: python, ip, raspberry-pi3, windows-server-2012-r2

I managed to make a program in python that, what it does is receive the weight of a scale and copy it to a file, then I made another program that reads that file, all this I have in a raspberry.
what I need is to have these two programs in the raspberry but the .txt where I write the weight I need it to have on a server running on windows server 12.
the inconvenience I am having is that when creating a .txt on the server, if I access that file from the raspberry it does not give me the necessary permissions to edit it, just to read ... someone knows how I can configure the raspberry to receive the File from the server with permissions to edit it? and I would like this file to be constantly refreshed in order to read the weight in real time.

**EDITION 1)**

Im using this code on de raspberry terminal:

`$sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

`$sudo mkdir /media/Balanza`

`$sudo mount -t cifs -o username=usuario,password=50922  //192.168.0.8/Balanzas  /media/Balanza`

`$sudo chmod 777 /media/Balanza`

`$sudo chmod 777 /media/Balanza/Balanza_1.txt`

*In the reading file I wrote:*

```
import time
import string
import serial
import socket

while True:
    f = open("/media/Balanza/Balanza_peso.txt")
    line = f.readline()
    print(line)
    f.close()
```

*in the writing file I wrote:*

```
####
####
####
f = open("/media/Balanza/Balanza_peso.txt","w")
f.write(datos+"\n")
```

When I start the reading program it goes OK.
But when I try to open the writing one, it sends me back this errno:

```
PermissionError:[Errno 13] Permission denied:'/media/Balanza/Balanza_peso.txt'
```

**actually I didn´t need to be that way, I can save a file on the raspberry and read it from the Server, but I find no way to do so, if anyone have another way to solve the problem it is very welcome**

**I forgot to tell, first of all, I share the windows folder with all permissions **

Comment: Write the files permissions before sending it over. It likely does not have global r/w. execute a `chmod +rw ./file` on it.

Comment: You really need to condense down your problem here, as the context is irrelevant. Write the command that is failing in addition to the error message you are receiving.

Comment: I agree with @Laif, please narrow down the problem as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at running a Flask application on your windows server to recieve incoming web requests?

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)

local_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
output_filename = 'Balanza_peso.txt'

@app.route('/temperature')
def my_endpoint():
    temp = request.args.get('temp')
    with open(os.path.join(local_path, output_filename), 'a') as out_file:
        out_file.write(f'temperature : {temp}')
    return (f'written the temperature {temp} to a local file')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

then it's a case of curling from your raspberry pi to your windows machine:

```sh
curl <windows server ip>:5000/temperature?temp=23
```

Comment: Im sry, but i´m not folowing you, cause i´m new at server enviorment, whats a flask application? how can I run it?

Comment: Flask is a lightweight webserver python library.  You can use it to create a simple web service which receives your temperature from your raspberry pi.  instead of writing out to a text file on the raspberry pi, you can use requests (another python package) to issue a post from your rpi application to your windows server.  in doing this, you have no need to link the filesystems of 2 uncommon operating systems together.

Comment: ohhh that´s a really good idea, i´m going to try that!! thanks